# Richfaces requirement jre version

Tags: jsf, richfaces, java

Does richfaces application require a minimum jre version on the browser to run.

Is it a must to have jre 1.5 and above version on the browser.

Comment: Java/JSF runs on webserver, produces HTML/CSS/JS and sends it to webbrowser. All the webbrowser retrieves is plain HTML/CSS/JS which it perfectly understands. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*. See, it's one and all HTML/CSS/JS (at least, if Java/JSF has done its job properly). I have no utter idea why you think that the webbrowser needs a JRE in order to interpret HTML/CSS/JS.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @BalusC explains why a JRE is not required when a client accesses an application using the RichFaces library.

If you are interested in the server, client, and development technical requirements, refer to the technical requirements section of the RichFaces documentation for the version you're using.  For example, documentation for the technical requirements for RichFaces 4.3.1 can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-RichFaces_overview.html#sect-Component_Reference-RichFaces_overview-Full_technical_requirements).